# How to do this specific task by a function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working  on this vertical scrolling gallery.
Now I cannot work it out but I need to make this code less verbose.
the code I've been writing is to repetative.
this is the code

```
var target1 = $("#myImg1").offset().top;
var target2 = $("#myImg2").offset().top;

if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target1 - 150 
 && $(window).scrollTop() <= target1 + 150) {
    showBgOnTop('#firstImage','#secondImage');  
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target2 - 150 
 && $(window).scrollTop() <= target2 + 150) {
    showBgOnTop('#secondImage','#firstImage');
}
```

**Can I use some kind of function** here to shorten the code.
Like an array.
please tell me what i am doing wrong here.
thanks.

Comment: can you show us an example how your vertical gallery should look like approx ? so we could provide better answer

Comment: Its long code but let me tell you the idea here.As the vertical thumbs move, the  background image related to that changes in background. #firstimage  bg pic moves to top.#secondImage moves to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

It seems like you have a jQuery object as your target that's linked to two images and you'd like to have multiple instances of this, say at least 2.

So my solution is to have an array of objects with this format

```
var array = [
    {target: ['image1', 'image2']}
]
```

`target` being the target element `id` and the value being an array of the ids of the associated images.

Now all the user has to do is keep on adding new objects to the array in the format shown above.

### Solution

```
// Put the target object id as keys and the array of the linked/associated elements as values
var arrs = [
        {'#myImg1': ['#firstImage', '#secondImage']},
        {'#myImg2': ['#secondImage', '#firstImage']},
        {'#myImg3': ['...', '...']} // keep adding new items as object here
    ],
    $windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // cache window scroll function

// loop through the array here
$.each(arrs, function (idx, obj) { 
    for (id in obj) {
        var $el = $(id), // cache the target element here
            args = obj[id],
            img1 = args[0].toString(),
            img2 = args[1].toString();

        if ($windowScrollTop >= $el - 150 && $windowScrollTop <= $el + 150) {
            showBgOnTop(img1, img2);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Can you explain it to me please. i am quite a new person here.

Comment: How about using Switch Case?

Comment: Then you can throw that in instead of the if idx block, but it could get potential long.

Comment: yeah but how about case for idx block, anyways thanks.

Comment: An explanation of why the solution is as it is would generally be helpful, @dcodesmith.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard any better now?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this actually is a jQuery function.

The only thing you can do to lessen the code is to use

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

as a variable:

```
var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Remaining part is a condition, you cannot use conditions are variables.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function show(image1id, image2id) {
  var target1 = $(image1id).offset().top;
  var target2 = $(image2id).offset().top;

  if (($(window).scrollTop() >= target2 - 150) &&
       $(window).scrollTop() <= target2 + 150)) {
    showBgOnTop(image1id, image2id);
  }
}

show('#firstImage','#secondImage');
show('#secondImage','#firstImage');
```